# Интеграция приложения Android/Windows с принтером

Tags: java, c#, android, принтер

Мне нужно интегрировать приложение Windows/Android с принтером этикеток чтобы при нажатии печатался текст который я передам. Какие есть подходящие для этого модели принтеров с Api? Соединение желательно по TCP/IP
Но можно и по блютуф или usb. Предпочтительно языки Java и C#.
Принтер будет использоваться для печати "этикеток" блюд в ресторане. Есть интеграция с устройствами Atol они могут вообще печатать не чеки а текст который я передаю?

Comment: Не оставляйте дополнительную информацию в комментариях, вы можете отредактировать вопрос. А комментарий удалите.

Comment: я пробовал печать с китайским оемом от зебры ZQ220. в андроиде интегрируется очень легко. но есть жирный минус из коробки только один м о н о ш и р н ы й русский шрифт, для печати на русском нужно конвертировать шрифт виндовый в шрифт на девайс. правда один раз. еще не самый сложный язык разметки, но для печати чека вполне сойдет, учитывая около нулевые затраты на его подключение в код. есть дизайнер этикеток, его код правда потом надо подправлять если нужен русский, но для разметки он вполне пригоден.

Comment: Yakov, посмотрел зебру что-то цены не особо демократичные 20-30К рублями, как-то дороговато для принтера этикеток под блюда, толи дело Xprinter там 3К такой стоит но правда SDK есть а Api не нашел

Comment: @Alcotrass-, поясните что значит SDK есть а API не нашли?) Если есть SDK - значит там уже есть все методы взаимодействия с устройством.

Comment: @AndreyMihalev Под Api имею ввиду документацию по SDK